# Как реализовать такой UI

Tags: java, android

Возник вопрос, как лучше, реализовать такой `UI`, изначально экран смотрится так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку плюс должно выглядеть вот так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое, что приходит в голову, это сделать `View`, с картинками, которому выставлять `Visability Gone` или `Visible` при нажатии на кнопку. Но возможно есть какие-то другие варианты, BottomSheet, например. Как лучше сделать?

Comment: делай тем способом, что легче для тебя

Comment: `BottomSheet` - единственный лёгкий вариант для выдвигаемого контента снизу. Там уже все настроено. Управлять видимостью - резко. Если хотите анимацию - `BotfomSheet`

Comment: @СергейГрушин А если это будет BottomSheet, то не будет проблем с тем, что верхняя строка со смайлом должна будет подниматься вверх, когда появляется BottomSheet?

Comment: Нужно всего лишь поставить якорь `anchor` и панель будет подниматься вместе с ним.

Comment: @СергейГрушин Спасибо, про anchor - это полезная информация!